# How do I safely delete a model field in Django?

Tags: python, django

I need to delete fields from an existing django model that already have a few objects associated with it. Deleting the fields from `models.py` gives me an error (obviously as there are table columns still associated with them). The data in `body2` and `body3` are not necessary for my app.
I have copied that data from those fields to the `body` field. How would I go about deleting these fields **without** dropping the table entirely?

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    #some fields

    body =EditorJsField(editorjs_config=editorjs_config)
    body2 =EditorJsField(editorjs_config=editorjs_config)
    body3 =EditorJsField(editorjs_config=editorjs_config)
```

I deleted `body2` and `body3` and ran migrations and when creating a new object, I get errors such as this.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "body2" of relation "second_posts" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (20, Wave | Deceptiveness, and unpredictability of nature, 2021-07-19 13:40:32.274815+00, 2021-07-19 13:40:32.274815+00, {"time":1626702023175,"blocks":[{"type":"paragraph","data":{"tex..., null, null, Just how unpredictable is nature? Nature is all around us, yet, ..., image/upload/v1626702035/dfaormaooiaa8felspqd.jpg, wave--deceptiveness-and-unpredictability-of-nature, #66c77c, l, 1, 1, 0).
```

This is the code that I'm using to save the sanitized data(after I've deleted those fields of course.)

```py
post = Posts.objects.create(
                body=form.cleaned_data.get('body'),
                #
            )
```

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the django migration docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody seemed to have an answer, and since it looked like this error was an anomaly, I went the non-python way and ran SQL queries and dropped the columns. For those of you who ran into the same problem,

### Warning, you will lose all the data in the fields you would like to delete using this method

**First, make Django aware of the changes**

Delete the fields you want to be deleted and run migrations.

*Before*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    #some fields

    body =EditorJsField(editorjs_config=editorjs_config)
    body2 =EditorJsField(editorjs_config=editorjs_config)
    body3 =EditorJsField(editorjs_config=editorjs_config)
```

*After*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    #some fields

    body =EditorJsField(editorjs_config=editorjs_config)
```

*Command Prompt*

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

**Drop the columns using SQL queries**

First connect to your database(I used [postgres](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/connect-to-postgresql-database/)). The name of the table should be something like `appname_model`. My app was called "Second" and the model was Post. So, the table was called `second_post`.

See if the columns still persist after the migrations using,

*In the SQL command prompt*

```
/d second_post
```

This should give you a nice diagram of the database with all the columns listed on the left side. To drop those columns, type,

```
ALTER TABLE second_post DROP COLUMN body2;
ALTER TABLE second_post DROP COLUMN body3;
```

After entering each query, the prompt should return a string `ALTER TABLE` if successful.

Comment: You should never do that manually as it'll desynchronize the actual database state from what Django thinks it should look like. Please double-check your migrations before and after the change, as it should never require any manual database modifications in such cases. If you have only initial migration and the new one, please post them. If you have more of them in the question, I can assist you with the extracting relevant ones, drop into the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235099/debugging-assist-for-how-do-i-safely-delete-a-model-field-in-django) to do that.

Comment: If you get an error doing the above, make sure you remove any reference to the field from models.py, admin.py and forms.py. After I remove these references to the field, the above solution worked very well.

Comment: it should be 

```
\d second_post
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop the data completely, you need to create a Django migration (using `./manage.py makemigrations` preferably) that will remove those columns from the database.

Alternatively, if you want to play safe and persist the old data, you can first make those fields as nullable, then create migrations for them and at the end either just don't use them anymore or remove those columns from the model, but don't reflect it in migrations (you'll need to fake the removal of those columns in migrations though if you'll ever need to run another migration in this app).

Comment: I actually did your first suggestion but that's when I got the error mentioned above. I'm thinking this is a problem with my database. I might need to run SQL queries and drop those columns

Comment: Did you run the migration?

Comment: yes I did. The migration ran fine. It's creating a new object that I can't do

Comment: this specific case seems like an anomaly since `makemigrations` didn't drop those columns. I ran SQL queries after migrating and it worked out fine.

Comment: @juztignoreme removing columns from the database manually may introduce more problems in the future. Please see my comment to your answer.